# Get the difference of unique elements of a flag-based ID in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an SQL table from which I want to extract unique elements by ID, comparing different groups, for example :

```
ID,Group,Product
a,2,33
a,1,83
b,3,51
c,2,33
b,1,20
a,3,20
b,2,51
a,2,83
```

If I have two products equals in different groups for the same ID, then I don't save them. Resulting this:

```
ID,Group,Unique
a,2,33
c,2,33
b,1,20
a,3,20
```

I'm trying this in SQL, but I don't know how to do it, please help me!

Comment: is in Teradata but is similar to any SQL, if you have any idea I will appreciate

Comment: Would you accept `a,33,2` however?

Comment: Yes, because `a,33,2` indicates `ID = a, Group = 33, Product = 2` and this product is not repeated in a different group for the same user.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all rows that have the same product and different groups:

```
select * 
from yourtable a 
where not exists(
    select 1 from yourtable b where a.Product = b.Product and a.Group <> b.Group
)
```

Comment: thanks! but this solution not return all values from differents products to the same group to any ID

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table_1
qualify count("product") over(partition by "group")=1
```

Comment: code-only answers are generally discouraged.  Please add some language describing this.

Answer (score 1):

One method is aggregation:

```
select id, max(group) as group, product
from t
group by id, product
having min(group) = max(group);
```